# Upload custom app in teams registered in another azure tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

Can I upload a custom app in my teams for tenant "A"(I have the upload custom app link enabled by teams admin) which is not published to the Teams App store yet.

The custom app contains a bot registered with Microsoft bot framework and does not contain tabs.

The Microsoft App Registration for this app is registered in other tenant "B" and the app doesn't require any special delegated or application permissions to Microsoft graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this should work no problem. Depending on what you app includes (Bot, Tab, etc.) these should work fine, provided:

1. the user's device can access the system no problem (e.g. if your tab is hosted on a public httpS url, versus let's say an internal-only address that only people in tenant "A" could access
2. you don't have any tenant-specific filtering on (for instance, there are bot samples that show how to -restrict- your bot to only users from a specific tenant). This is NOT the default though, you would have put this into your bot specifically. By default it will work fine across tenants.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. the custom app contains a just a bot and no tabs. I have edited the question to include this detail. The company from tenant A are uploading the custom app in their org catalog. The app is provided by company with tenant B. How does the app discover the bot? is it through the bot registration id?

Comment: Yes that's correct, it's via the registration id. Teams knows that the bot -has- to registered with MS Bot Framework, so it only goes there to look up the bot info (esp. the endpoint), and it uses the bot's unique id to do this.

Comment: Right. It should work without any problem.